# Get user rank position based on total score and time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get the user rank position based on the total score and average time. However, the query I am using gives the wrong position number.

```php
$myId = TotalScore::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
$position = TotalScore::where('ts', '>=', $myId->ts)
    ->where('avg_times_taken', '>=', $myId->avg_times_taken)->count();
```

**Table structure**

[image]

Let's say I want to know my rank position. The query needs to compare my total score (ts) and the average time taken (`avg_times_taken`) and display my position. If two users get the same score, the one with the lower average time ranked better.

Comment: Is the rank the total score, or the total score divided by the average time taken ?

Comment: it's actually based on maximum total score and minimum average time taken.

Comment: what is the relationship between the total score (ts) and the average time taken (avg_times_taken)

Comment: let say I want to know my rank position. 
query need to compare my total score (ts) and my average time is taken (avg_times_taken) in this table and show my position

Comment: that's still not enough... if two users get the same score, is the one with lower average time ranked better ? and if a user has more score but took more time than another one, which one is ranked better ?

Comment: @PHPnoob if two users get the same score, is the one with lower average time ranked better

Comment: Since i don't know how laravel works, would a mysql query be enough ?

Comment: @PHPnoob sure maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comments, it is clear that total score and the average time taken are inversely related. I.e. the ratio between the total_score and average_time_taken, should give us some value that we'll now use to position or order our records. 
Hence, first, I would introduce another column in the table and calculate the ratio. 
Assuming we call the column `ratio_average`

to get values for our column simply take `total_score / average_time_taken`

so now when fetching our results from the table we'd only have to do the following:

```
TotalScore::orderBy('ratio_average', 'desc')->get();
```

Above will now give you the results in the correct order of positions from the first position

Comment: there's no ratio, rank is ordered first by score then by time if i understood

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to do this way, by getting I have to use array search which takes too much time execution when it comes too many users

Comment: No, you are not getting to any array's or anything, all you got to do, is introduce the column where you will calculate the ratio (you can insert this when saving records, but for existing records just run a mysql command to do the calculations). Then with that just pull all records and order them with the new column

Answer (score 1):

This is what a MySQL query would look like :

```
SELECT 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM TableScore X
      WHERE X.ts > T.ts OR (X.ts = T.ts AND X.avg_times_taken < T.avg_times_taken)
    ) + 1 AS position   
FROM TableScore T      
WHERE T.user_id = '7';
```

[WORKING DB-FIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wmC6xzjSfCUqXGR5PuNefd/4)